# how to partly reverse a character's color? (its 33% to the left is black and 67% to the right is white)

Tags: css

When Chrome or Firefox is used on this page:

[a page on dell.com](http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=dxcwpp1&c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&kc=productdetails~desktop-studio-xps-435)

(or most any product page should work).  There are 4 tabs, and if we click on the last tab for "Review", the status bar will have characters that is partly reversed.  For example, the letter "v" can have 66% to the left being white and 33% to the right being black.  I am pretty sure it is not done by Flash, as the mouse right-click doesn't show any Flash plug-in menu.  Does someone know how it can be done?

screenshot:

[alt text http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/2696/partlyreversed.png](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/2696/partlyreversed.png)

Comment: That Dell page you mention is a pretty good example of how *not* to do it. Boy, what an awful way of animating *just about everything*.

Comment: @Tomalak don't you think it gives a little bit classiness to how they make it work like a Windows widget?

Comment: @Jian Lin: To be honest, I probably wouldn't bother to mimic the behavior of a Windows 95 style progress bar on a web page. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I imagine the word is actually there twice, once in each colour, but the white version is clipped by the progress bar.

Comment: using the left div to "show through" part of the white text huh?  that's smart.

Comment: +1 For this smart hack. It probably is done this way. Great idea man!

Answer (score 2):

Sample:

```
<div style="width:400px; height:1.1em; position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute; text-align:center; width:400px; height:100%; background-color:#eee;">49 %</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; width:195px; height:100%; background-color:#347;">
        <div style="width:400px; text-align: center; color: #ace;">49 %</div>
    </div>
</div>
```